# Nifi route files based on an attribute without specifying the attribute value

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to create a nifi flow in which we will be querying files data from postgres and indexing them in druid. I will be getting, different months of data and I will be adding an attribute as **month** and from the flow file the value will be assigned, I want my flow to be dynamic such that if multiple flow files consist a same month they should be routed to next processor, and we need to do the ingestion based on the latest month(current month data should ingest 1st) and it should go in descending order. Is there any possible way to do this?